# Getting warning message while printing column based data in shiny app

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to write a shiny app to display column-wise data. The code works but getting warning message in RStudio.

The warning is as follows:

`Warning: Error in [.data.frame: undefined columns selected
Stack trace (innermost first):
    82: [.data.frame
    81: [
    80: print
    79: renderTable [/media/ubuntu/C2ACA28AACA27895/Windows/work/R/Shiny_Apps/hos_performance/patsatsys.R#40]
    78: func
    77: origRenderFunc
    76: output$tab1
     1: runApp`

Following is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)        

ui <- fluidPage(

  navbarPage(title = "PATSATSYS",
             tabPanel("DataSets", 
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'text/plain', '.csv')),
                          selectInput("dcol", "Choose the Column", choices = " ", selected = " ")
                      ), 
                        mainPanel(tableOutput("tab1"))
                    )
         ),
             tabPanel("Discriptives", textOutput("sum-1")),
             tabPanel("Revenue/Cost", textOutput("text-1")),
             tabPanel("Performance", textOutput("text-2"))
         )
  )


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data_input <- reactive({
    infile <- input$file1
    req(infile)
    data.frame(read.csv(infile$datapath)) 
  })

  observeEvent(input$file1,{
    updateSelectInput(session,
                  inputId = "dcol",
                  choices = names(data_input()))
  }
  )

  output$tab1 <- renderTable({
    df <- data_input()
    print(df[input$dcol])

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am expecting code to be executed without warning message. How to get rid of warning message?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
  output$tab1 <- renderTable({
    data_input()[[input$dcol]]
  })
```